# SQL. Запрос с COUNT

Tags: sql, firebird, count

Затрудняюсь корректно составить запрос. 
Нужно узнать сколько комментариев написал каждый (опр. из списка) пользователь за опр. период даты.

**Получить количество созданных комментариев с  "01.01.2019" по "01.07.2019" у пользователей с ID - 1,2,22,59.**

Структура БД (разрабатывал не я):

```
Таблица History

    NOTE - Текст комментария (VARCHAR)
    DATECR - Дата создания коммента (DATE)
    IDCREATOR - ID создателя (INTEGER)
```

и

```
Таблица Users

    IDUSER - id юзера (INTEGER)
    NAME - ФИО юзера (VARCHAR)
```

Как получить кол-во комментариев для одного пользователя я понимаю, но как сделать выборку для нескольких сразу(если это возможно силами SQL)?

В вывод хочу получить таблицу с 2 столбцами - ФИО юзера и кол-во комментариев.

Мой вариант для одного пользователя:

```
select 
      COUNT(*)
from
      history
where
      (history.idcreator = 59)
       and
      (history.datecr between "01.01.2019" and "01.07.2019")
```

С уважением,  Waik/

Comment: `WHERE id IN (ids list) AND ...`. Ну или `WHERE (id=id1 OR id=id2 OR ...) AND ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простой запрос с группировкой:

```
SELECT u.id, count(h.id) as count_history FROM
users as u JOIN history as h ON u.id = h.idcreator
WHERE u.id in (1,2,22,59) AND h.datecr BETWEEN "01.01.2019" AND "01.07.2019"
GROUP BY u.id
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Запрос не захотел работать с командой AS, пришлось убрать. И как поправить запрос, если у пользователя нет комментариев он отображался в таблице, но COUNT был бы 0.

Comment: @Waik заменить `JOIN` на `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: @ГерманБорисов спасибо, но странно отрабатывает. Не на всех пользователей.

Comment: Ошибся чуть-чуть. Нужно еще `AND h.datecr BETWEEN …` перенести из `WHERE` в условие соединения `ON u.id = h.idcreator AND h.datecr BETWEEN …`

Comment: @ГерманБорисов спасибо. Теперь все отлично!